# Nested NSScrollViews that can be scrolled with different gestures?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsscrollview, nsresponder, trackpad

I've got an app with an `NSScrollView` nested inside another `NSScrollView`. I'd like the user to be able to scroll the inner scrollview using two-finger swipe, and to scroll the outer scrollview using three fingers.

I imagine I'll need to somehow configure each scrollview to reject touches with the wrong numbers of fingers, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! The trick is to subclass the inner `ScrollView` and force it to reject gestures that have a certain number of touches, forwarding them to the parent scrollview:

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event {
    if (_forwardScrollToParent) {
        // [self.enclosingScrollView scrollWheel:event];
    } else {
        [super scrollWheel:event];
        [self recordInteractionWithThisTab];
    }
}

- (void)touchesBeganWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    [super touchesBeganWithEvent:event];
    NSInteger nTouches = [event touchesMatchingPhase:NSTouchPhaseTouching inView:self].count;
    if (nTouches == 3) {
        _forwardScrollToParent = YES;
    } else {
        _forwardScrollToParent = NO;
    }
}
```